# How do I make a news-like lower third in kdenlive?

Tags: video, editing

With the composite transition in kdenlive I am already able to let the the [lower third](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_third) (with the name and a line of additional information, just like in the news) appear. Now I want it to fade in (or some other effect), but kdenlive only allows to add one transition.

Is there a way to avoid this dilemma?

Comment: I don't know kdenlive, but the bar you are referring to is often called a lower third.

Comment: thank you, that really could help, since i am not a native speaker obviously and had a little trouble finding the name of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an affine transform for the title

1. Create a title with the text
2. Put the video on track 2
3. Put the title on track 1
4. Combine them with an affine transformation
5. On the affine transformation, add 4 key frames for a title of 5 seconds, at 0 / 1 / 4 / 5 seconds
6. Set the opacity for keyframe at second 0 and second 5 to 0. Keyframes at second 1 and 4 keep 100% opacity
7. Play. The title fades in for a second, stays for 3 seconds and fades out for a second.

Screencast: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/kdenlive-lower-third.htm

Comment: thank you for the very desciptive answer, as well as the video !
This really seems like a nice and straight forward solution.